# Django: How change the password of another user

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I'm constructing site by Django.
I'm setting some authentications in this site, like Site Manager, Group Manager and Normal User.
When System Manager or Group Manager logged in, they could change the password of Normal Users as a part of system management.
In django, PasswordChangeForm or SetPasswordForm provide some user password change form. I think these forms are for changing password of users themselves.
Yes, I need that too. But I also need the form of changing the password of another users like django admin site.
How can I construct the form ?

I read the code of django's admin site.
I found AdminPasswordChangeForm, can I use this class ?

```
forms.py

class MyAdminPasswordChangeForm(AdminPasswordChangeForm):
    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = user
        super().__init__(user, *args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields.values():
            field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
```

```
views.py

class PasswordChange(PasswordChangeView):
    form_class = MyAdminPasswordChangeForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('password_change_done')
    template_name = 'accounts/password_change/password_admin_change.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'user_id' in self.request.session:
            user = User.objects.get(id=self.request.session['user_id'])
            form_class = self.get_form_class()
            form = form_class(user=user)

        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())

    def get_form_class(self):
        return self.form_class
```

Comment: I think you can do that already from django admin site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use set_password() for change user passwords
first you should select user with such code

```
user=User.objects.get(username=username)
```

then you can set password

```
user.set_password(password)
user.save()
```